# JQuery Dialog Grip Icon positioning problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using the JQuery UI Dialog plug-in.  Everything works great except for where the "resize" grip icon is being placed.  It is in the Left-Bottom corner of the dialog instead of the Right-Bottom corner.  I rolled the theme using ThemeRoller as JQueryUI.com.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into the same thing, and there seem to be two culprits:

1. I tried to download just the theme by unselecting all the jQuery UI components. I'm fairly certain that's what resulted in relevant CSS just plain getting left out (a whole chunk of dialog styles, in this case). So step one, make sure you have the components checked that you'll be using, even if you're just trying to roll a different theme.
2. The CSS still was a little off for me, and I had to add `position: absolute` to the `.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se` style.

Hope this helps some other desperate Google searcher. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) didn't generate the CSS file for the theme correctly.  Had to adjust the position of the draggable icon in the CSS file.